# can not download gnome-core dependencies for arm64 machine

Tags: debian, apt, gnome, dependencies, arm

I want to download `gnome-core` package dependencies  to install on a debian 10 arm-64 device ,so I used this command :

```
sudo apt-cache depends  -i gnome-core:arm64 | awk '/Depends:/ {print $2}' | xargs  apt-get download
```

and got this errors :

```
E: Unable to locate package <adwaita-icon-theme:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <fonts-cantarell:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <sound-theme-freedesktop:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <gnome-backgrounds:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <gnome-session:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <gnome-shell-extensions:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <gnome-user-docs:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <gsettings-desktop-schemas:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <firefox:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <chromium-browser:arm64>
E: Unable to locate package <system-config-printer-common:arm64>
```

arm64 architecture was enabled previously using `dpkg --add-architecture arm64`   and both `main` and `contrib` repositories were enable however, I did `apt update` and `apt-get update` then I retried but no change was occurred and got same errors.

I'm using a debian 10 buster x86-64 WSL machine.

what is the problem and how can I download that dependencies ?

Comment: Have you enabled the `arm64` architecture on your amd64 machine? Or enabled foreign-architecture apt sources? Have you read [the multiarch howto](https://wiki.debian.org/Multiarch/HOWTO)?

Comment: @Gilles'SO-stopbeingevil' I forgot to say that,yes I had enabled it using `dpkg --add-architecture arm64`  before running that bash command ,I updated the question and added this.

Comment: Ah, WSL! That’s rather significant. Is it WSL or WSL2?

Comment: @StephenKitt it is WSL2 but doesn't matter anymore.I did your great solution with a debian 10 buster live dvd and that solved my problem.but let me ask another question, there is a lot of downloaded packages how can I install them ?(I got confused with which ones must be first because of dependencies)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`apt-cache`’s output can’t be parsed in this way; you’re ending up with

```
...
  Depends: <adwaita-icon-theme:arm64>
    adwaita-icon-theme
...
```

and you’re extracting `<adwaita-icon-theme:arm64>` which isn’t a valid package name.

Angle brackets in `apt-cache depends`’ output mean that the resolver didn’t find a version to install, and the following lines show what should be installed instead  — for `adwaita-icon-theme`, this happens because it’s marked as “Multi-Arch: foreign” which allows the native version to satisfy the dependency.

In addition to this, you’re not parsing alternative dependencies, for example

```
 |Depends: firefox-esr:arm64
 |Depends: firefox:arm64
 |Depends: chromium:arm64
 |Depends: <chromium-browser:arm64>
```

You only need to install one of these, not all of them.

All of this makes it really difficult to use `apt-cache` to build up a list of packages to download for a foreign architecture. You’d be better off using a foreign minimal chroot and `apt-get install --download-only`:

- install `mmdebstrap`:

  ```
  sudo apt install mmdebstrap qemu-user qemu-user-static binfmt-support libfakeroot:arm64 libfakechroot:arm64
  ```
- set up a default `arm64` chroot:

  ```
  sudo mmdebstrap --architectures=arm64 buster gnome-core-arm64
  ```
- enter the chroot:

  ```
  sudo chroot gnome-core-arm64
  ```
- download the `gnome-core` dependencies:

  ```
  apt-get update
  apt-get install --download-only gnome-core
  ```
- exit the chroot, and you’ll find the package files in `gnome-core-arm64/var/cache/apt/archives`.

Comment: sorry, I didn't understand your alternative solution . could you please solution your way a bit more?I

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: I ran `sudo mmdebstrap --architectures=arm64 buster gnome-core-arm64` and got this error: `/usr/sbin/chroot: failed to run command ‘env’: Exec format error  ` (the error was too long ,due to character limitation I just copied main part of it)